# Micronaut's netty server http request missing headers

Tags: http, netty, micronaut, micronaut-rest, micronaut-security

I'm trying to integrate custom authentication service with micronaut security and to do this I've implemented my own AuthenticationProvider and that works fine for basic auth, however I also need to take care of authentication tokens passed in the request.

To do this I'm trying to implement my own AuthenticationFetcher and in the fetchAuthentication method I'm trying to get my custom authentication header and then authenticate the request.

```
  @Override
    public Publisher<Authentication> fetchAuthentication(HttpRequest<?> request) {
        if (request.getHeaders().get(authConfiguration.getTokenHeader()) != null) {
```

The issue I'm having is that netty's request.getHeaders() doesn't return all headers that are being sent to the webservice (I confirmed from my browsers developer console)

```
GET /service/all HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Cookie: m=2258:Z3Vlc3Q6Z3Vlc3Q%253D
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1 Safari/605.1.15
Accept-Language: pl-pl
Referer: http://localhost:4200/campaigns
Connection: keep-alive
X-Token: my.token.here
```

[image: headers visible in webservice]

And here are my app settings

```
micronaut:
  server:
    netty:
      maxHeaderSize: 1024
      worker:
        threads: 4
      parent:
        threads: 4
      childOptions:
        autoRead: true
  application:
    name: appName
```

Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by cors config:

```
micronaut:
  server:
    cors:
      enabled: true
```

After adding this my request header was removed in the filter chains.